# I am having this error ORA-00917: missing comma?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-insert

I am working to insert data from two table into one table but I am getting this error "SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma " but I don't know where is the issue: Any help are welcome thanks.

```
INSERT INTO NAME_PROFFESION(NAME_ID AS 'NAME ID' , PROFFESION_ID AS 'PROFFESIONID' )
SELECT NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID 
FROM  NAME
INNER JOIN PROFFESION 
ON NAME.PROFFESION_ID = PROFFESION.PROFFESION_ID;
```

The error:

```
Error starting at line : 107 in command -
 INSERT INTO NAME_PROFFESION(NAME_ID AS 'NAME ID' , PROFFESION_ID AS 'PROFFESIONID' )
 SELECT NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID 
 FROM  NAME
 INNER JOIN PROFFESION 
 ON NAME.PROFFESION_ID = PROFFESION.PROFFESION_ID
 Error at Command Line : 107 Column : 37
 Error report -
 SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
 00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:
```

And if I remove the AS I will get that error:

```
  Error starting at line : 107 in command -
  INSERT INTO NAME_PROFFESION(NAME_ID , PROFFESION_ID )
  SELECT NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID 
  FROM  NAME
  INNER JOIN PROFFESION 
  ON NAME.PROFFESION_ID = PROFFESION.PROFFESION_ID
  Error at Command Line : 108 Column : 17
  Error report -
 SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
 *Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: I don't think `as` is part of the column definition in an `insert`.

Comment: Ok I did edit the post

Comment: As has been mentioned, `NAME_ID AS 'NAME ID'` doesn't make sense in the column list of an insert statement. Moreover, single quotes are for string delimiters, so if you want column aliases in some other query, remember to use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
INSERT INTO NAME_PROFFESION(NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID)
SELECT N.NAME_ID, N.PROFFESION_ID 
FROM NAME N
INNER JOIN PROFFESION P ON P.PROFFESION_ID = N.PROFFESION_ID;
```

That is:

- the columns list of `INSERT` does not take aliases, just column names
- all columns should qualified (prefixed) with the table they belong to, to avoid ambiguity when the same column is available in more than one table - table aliases come handy for this

Side note: as it is, your query could also be written:

```
INSERT INTO NAME_PROFFESION(NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID)
SELECT N.NAME_ID, N.PROFFESION_ID 
FROM NAME N
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PROFFESION WHERE P.PROFFESION_ID = N.PROFFESION_ID);
```

Comment: thanks but still have the same issue error SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @Omar: please run the query exactly as provided. This should not raise that error.

Comment: Thank you but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try without the aliases for the fields, also there is a double space in `FROM  NAME`:

```
INSERT INTO NAME_PROFFESION(NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID)
SELECT NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID 
FROM NAME
INNER JOIN PROFFESION 
ON NAME.PROFFESION_ID = PROFFESION.PROFFESION_ID;
```

EDIT:

The ambiguity is because there is no alias for the tables. So, try:

```
INSERT INTO NAME_PROFFESION(NAME_ID, PROFFESION_ID)
SELECT n.NAME_ID, n.PROFFESION_ID 
FROM NAME n
INNER JOIN PROFFESION p
ON n.PROFFESION_ID = p.PROFFESION_ID;
```

Comment: thanks but still have the same issue error SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @Omar have you tried the edited code? That should work just fine